# Corrupt folder won't delete in Trash

Tags: windows-7, macos, file-permissions

My Mac Air runs both OS X 10.9.4 and Windows 7. There is a folder that won't delete in Windows, but I successfully put it in Trash in Mac. However, I can't delete it from Trash.

I have tried pressing Option while clicking Empty Trash, but it didn't work. I tried numerous Terminal commands, but it either said input/output error or that the directory is not empty. I can rename the folder in Trash, but I can't even put it back (there is no such option).

What should I do??

Comment: you sure that hard drive isn't a bad drive?

Comment: what effect does `rm -rf` have on the folder? How about `sudo rm -rf`?

Answer (score 0):

Where was situated your folder before deleting ? Was it in the windows 7 partition, in the osx partition or in an exchange partition ? By default, osx and windows doesn't support other OS partitions.

Anyway, you can try to use terminal and go to the trash folder using this command: `cd /Users/YOUR_USERNAME/.Trash`, and then type `sudo rm -R YOUR_FOLDER`.
Command prompt will ask your password, you have to enter it but it won't show at all in the terminal (not even stars or dots) for security reasons.
Once entered, hit enter to validate and if you don't get an error message, your folder is deleted.